# Access Private Repositories from docker container as a npm dependency

Tags: docker

I am trying inject my ssh on build process

```
docker build --ssh default=C:\Users\***\.ssh\id_rsa .

// package.json
"airbase-common": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/******/airbase-common.git"

// error
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/******/airbase-common.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: 
If anyone as i am bulding his image in windows environment you should to keep .ssh folder  as neighbor your Dockerfile

```
// Dockerfile

FROM node:12.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
COPY  .ssh /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 644 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
VOLUME [ "/root/.ssh" ]
RUN npm install
.... etc
```